# How Do I Load A Assets Bundle

Tags: scripting, runtime-error, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

So I have created this object which is supposed to load a game over screen whenever I touch a gameobject. However, when I run it, I get this run time error

> Scene 'A' (-1) couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the
>   build settings or the asset bundle has not been loaded. To add a scene
>   to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
>   UnityEngine.Application:LoadLevel(String)
>   NewBehaviourScript:OnCollisionEnter(Collision) (at
>   Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs:10)

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name =="Hurt") 
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("A");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means your scene is missing from the Build Settings.

Go to File-> Build settings then you are given a window, you need to drag and drop all the needed scenes.

That is not related to Asset Bundle.

Comment: ' drag and drop'..is the most important thing in there.

Comment: That's crazy but it's true.  I "re-dragged" my scenes back into the build settings and suddenly no more error.